# How to provide parameter to the $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes

I use AngularJS for my App.

How to provide parameter callbackUrl after '?' to the $routeProvider.

The final url should be like this:
'/admin/test/profile/123456/edit?callbackUrl=W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd'

// src/js/routingUI.js

```
...
$routeProvider
                        .when('/admin/test/profile/:profileId/edit?callbackUrl', {
                            template: '<test-profile-edit></test-profile-edit>'
                        });
```

// testProfileDetails.js

```
 goToTestEdit() {
        const callbackURL = btoa(this.$location);
        const self = this;
        this.$timeout(function() {
            self.$location.path(
                '/admin/test/profile/' +
                self.testProfile.id +
                '/edit?callbackUrl=' + callbackURL);
        }, 1);
    }
```

// test-profile-details.html

```
<a ng-click="testProfileDetailsCtrl.goToTestEdit()">
       Edit
</a>
```

But now it just redirects to the URL '/#!/'

Answer (score 0):

I removed '?callbackUrl' part inside $routeProvider:

// src/js/routingUI.js

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/admin/test/profile/:profileId/edit', {
                      template: '<test-profile-edit></test-profile-edit>'
        });
```